# How to access NSIndexPath section value?

Tags: ios, swift, nsindexpath

I cannot understand why in the following code, `indexPath.section` is retuning a null value.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell? {
    NSLog("Index Path %@", indexPath)
    // Index Path <NSIndexPath: 0x1666d1d0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}

    NSLog("Index Path Section %@", indexPath.section)
    // Index Path Section (null)
```

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040405/nsindexpath-does-not-have-a-member-name-row-error-in-swift) I have also tried the following to access the section value:

```
if let section = indexPath?.section {
    NSLog("Index Path Section %@", section)
}
```

I have a table with 2 sections with 1 row in each section.  On the first iteration where `path = 0 - 0`, the log shows `Index Path Section (null)`.  On the second iteration where `path = 1 - 0` the program crashes.

I'm not trying to do anything complicated, I just need to access the section value so that I can conditionally return the correct type of cell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are access the section value correctly. You are just print it the wrong way.

`section` have type of `NSInteger`, which is `Int` in swift

just change log to `NSLog("Index Path Section %d", indexPath.section)`

It print `(null)` because the section value is `0`. and crashed when it is `1` because it is not valid object pointer

Comment: Thanks - I managed to figure it out myself. Now I have a problem with dequeuing cells but the compiler in this first seed really doesn't give you much to go on!

Comment: Alternatively use the print() and println() methods rather than NSLog, e.g. println("Index Path Section \\(indexPath.section)")